# Create recursive menu function with infinite submenus

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I'm trying to create a recursive function that's create a menu if relatedId is undefined and if id === relatedId create a submenu and the Json will be something like this :

RelatedId is a reference of a father ID

NOTE * I can add more elements in this JSON, isn't a fixed object
https://pastebin.com/01RZ7mS5

I'm have problems to this workly properly

My Code right now is, I'm using MongoDB to retrieve the info

```
    const getMastersMenu = await Menu.find()
    let MenuArray: any = []
    let SubMenuArray : any = []
    getMastersMenu.map((menu: any) => { 
        MenuArray.push({id: menu._id.toString(), name : menu.name, relatedId : menu?.relatedId})
    })

 const findRecursiveMenus = (menuItems: any) => {

            if (menuItems) {
              let newList: any = [];
              menuItems.map((menu: any) => {

                const findRelationship = menuItems.some((el: any, i: any) => {
                    return el.id === menu.relatedId
                })

                console.log(findRelationship)

                if(menu.relatedId === undefined){
                    let ObjectSubmenu = {id: menu.id, name : menu.name}
                    newList.push(ObjectSubmenu)

                } else if (findRelationship){
                    let returnedList = findRecursiveMenus({submenus : {id: menu.id, name : menu.name, relatedId : menu.relatedId}})                    
                    newList.push(returnedList)
                }
            })
            return newList;
          }
        }
```

Comment: Do you still need help on this? If so, you should probably describe the shape of `menuItems`, and explain whether your linked JSON is your input or desired output. In the latter case, what is the corresponding input?